# How to convert a string column containing a '$' and ',' to integer type

Tags: python, pandas, string, integer, valueerror

I'm trying to plot a dataframe in pandas. There is a price column in the dataframe containing the $ sign and floating numbers. Now if I convert it to int through `car_sales\["Price"\]= car_sales\["Price"\].str.replace('\[$,.\]', '').astype(int)`, I get an error like this:

> `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '$4,000 '

How can I solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Use `regex=True` in `replace`

Answer (score 0):

The default for `str.replace` is now `regex=False`, explicitly pass `regex=True`.

```
car_sales["Price"]= car_sales["Price"].str.replace('[$,.]', '', regex=True).astype(int)
```